# What does `se.chao1` mean? Vegan package

Tags: r, vegan

What does `se.chao1` mean in the results of my `estimateR`? This is using the `vegan` package in `R`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard error of Chao's estimator of number of unseen species.